# jQuery not changing data-text attribute on twitter-share-button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter

I am attempting to change the `data-text=""` attribute in the html below using a simple jQuery event, but it fails silently for some reason. Here is the html:

```
<!-- Quote Section -->
<div class="row m-spacer">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bg-light">
        <h3 class="text-dark">The Random Quoter</h3>
        <p>Generate a random quote, with the click of a button.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-dark m-3" id="quote-btn" type="button">Show me a quote!</button>
        <p class="text-muted mx-5" id="quote-line"></p>
        <p class="text-muted mx-5" id="quote-author"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Twitter Sharing Section -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bg-dark">
        <h3 class="text-light d-flex justify-content-center align-text-top m-4">Tweet That Quote!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bg-dark d-flex justify-content-center m-spacer">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"
           class="twitter-share-button m-4"
           data-show-count="false"
           data-text="This text should be replaced with the quote above."
           data-size="large">Tweet</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and here is the relevant jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Quote Button:
    $("#quote-btn").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(quote) {
            $("#quote-line").html(quote[0]["content"]);
            $("#quote-author").text("-" + quote[0]["title"]);
            var quoteText = $("#quote-line").text();
            $(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-text", quoteText);
        });
    });
}); //End of doc-ready.
```

I've included the cdn for widgets.js in the scripts:

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

Am I just missing a really simple step here? When the quote-button is clicked, it should replace the `data-text` attribute with the text from the quote-line. It just doesn't. I read all over the documentation, and cannot discern what I've done incorrectly. I'd appreciate a link to the spot in the documentation you reference, if you care to include it. Here is where I was all day: [Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button)

Comment: Use `$(".twitter-share-button").data('text', quoteText);`

Comment: I didn't see any effect when I made that change, sorry!

Comment: You had it right along. `$(".twitter-share-button").attr('data-text', quoteText);` works https://jsfiddle.net/rainbowseven/feqckjg8/3/,
if you're also looking to replace the button text that's a different matter. That's `$(".twitter-share-button").text(quoteText);`